# Overloading ostream& operator<<: how to force outputting zeroes?

Tags: c++, formatting, iostream

I want to overload

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const myType& y)
```

in order to output big unsigned integers represented in myType by a vector of `unsigned short`. So if the vector in question has, say, the elements `1f, a356, 13d5` I want to get the output `1fa35613d5` -- right now I only need this for `hex` or `oct` output.
In particular, `1, 0, 0` should be output to `100000000`. I want to acchieve this by successively outputting the elements of the vector. What I do get with this method, however, is `100`, despite the fact that I set

```
out.width(4);
out.fill('0');
out << std::internal;
out << std::noskipws;
```

Of course I could first write the `ushort` to a string and then output that, but I'd prefer to only use formatting instructions for `out` cause this makes it easier to respect the `hex` or `oct` settings of `out`. Which formatting option am I missing here?

Comment: Building your own string is going to be so very much more efficient (faster, use less memory) than using a hex or octal format for an `ostream`, that I'd go to the extra trouble of checking the current base and then doing my own formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following program prints fixed-width hex characters:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<unsigned short int> v { 10, 25, 0, 2000 };

    for (auto n : v)
    {
        std::cout << "0x" << std::hex << std::setfill('0')
                  << std::setw(4) << n << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0x000a
0x0019
0x0000
0x07d0
```

If you're writing a formatting function for this, you don't have to repeat `std::hex`, as that's permanent. Preserving the state of an ostream is a bit tricky, though, so perhaps you should look into something like Boost's state-saver.

Comment: Thanks, this did not really solve my problem but gave me the hint I needed. I (wrongly) assumed that out.width(n) _permanently_ sets the width, but it does so only for one output operation.